# Changing datepicker UI date gives error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, smarty, uidatepicker

My datepicker works fine until I change the date. After I change the date it shows: `The specified value "24-05-2017" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".`

Smarty HTML:

```
{assign var="value" value=$value|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'}
<div class="select{if $value === '1000-01-01' || $value|substr:0:4 === '1000'} no-date{/if}">
    {assign var="dateFormat" value="dd-mm-yy"}
    <div class='input-group date'>
        <input type='date' class="form-control {if $value === '1000-01-01' || $value|substr:0:4 === '1000'}no-date{/if}" name="{$name|escape}" id="edit-{$name|escape}"{if $value} value="{$value|escape}" placeholder="{$value|escape}"
               data-role="datepicker" data-date-format="{$dateFormat|escape}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
self.datepicker = function()
{
    if (typeof jQuery.ui !== 'undefined')
    {
        $('[data-role="datepicker"]').each(function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            var date = new Date($this.val());
            date = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

            console.log(date);
            var defaults = {
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: $this.data('date-format'),
                defaultDate: date === '1-1-1000' ? null : date,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: 'c-10:c+10'
            };

            var options = $.extend({}, defaults, $this.data('options'));

            console.log(options);
            $this.datepicker(options);
        });
    }
```

Results:
[image]

The image shows the console logs and the error. I'm not sure where the "yyyy-MM-dd" comes from, cause I have never assigned it or used it anywhere except for `$value`, but that is neccesary for `value` otherwise I get NaN when I try to get the value date with Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Set the dateFormat to:

```
dateFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy"
```